# How to search for questions and content about C programming

Tags: c, search-engine, terminology

I've recently revived my C interest, which means I have a lot of interest in certain articles and questions covering topics within the language.

Over the years I've grown accustomed to using search engines for this, by entering a query like "how to use [library] in [programming language]". This works very well, but frequently it doesn't for C.

Most likely this is due to it being a single letter, and some websites and search engines probably treat it as an insignificant part of the query (like "a" or "to").

When searching on specific websites such as SO, I can use tags, but overall I still experience a lack of content compared to other programming languages.

Is there any "standard" way to include C in queries or inputs like this? With C++ for example, a lot of content can be found using "cpp", so maybe there's a comparable format-friendly term for C.

Answer (score 0):

To search that in Google, if you want the search engines to treat a string as important, put it in double quotations as follows.

```
"important" 
"c"
```